# TypeError at / context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

I had an application that was build on Django 1.9 but now I have upgraded it to 2.2. Well, I have encountered a strange error and I'm unable to solve it using the existing similar solutions. 
In my case, we are fetching the templateResponse from a different file then the built in one

[Say x.py]-

```
class TemplateResponse(DefaultResponse):
"""A normal response involving data that can be sent to fill in a
template.  Since the template is specific to HTML responses, when
a JSON response is desired, this class is indistinguishable
from DefaultResponse."""

def __init__(self, template, data, status=200):
    self.data = data
    self.template = template
    self.status = status
```

[Base.py]-

```
def home(guts): 
    return TemplateResponse(template, {'c_sk': c_nt,
                                   'd_sk_count': d_sk_count}
```

Traceback Error -

```
response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/new_cl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
    ▶ Local vars 

/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/new_cl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
    ▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in inner
                return func(*args, **kwds) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/new_cl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/main/x.py in g
            response = seed.sprout(context, format) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/main/x.py in sprout
            return self.sprout_html(context) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/main/x.py in sprout_html
        body = self.template.render(context) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/new_cl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render
        context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape) …
    ▶ Local vars
/home/gaurav/Desktop/a Upgrade Work/a/new_cl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py in make_context
        raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__) …
    ▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Do let me know if anything is missing, I'll add it asap:)

Comment: You haven't shown the code in `TemplateResponse` (or perhaps `DefaultResponse`) that renders the template. Show the code that uses `RequestContext`.

Comment: Please use the *Switch to copy-paste view* button to make the traceback more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the incoming request to TemplateResponse

```
def home(request):
    response = TemplateResponse(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'c_sk': c_nt,'d_sk_count': d_sk_count} )
    return response
```

Comment: That's how you use [Django's TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects), but the OP is using a difference class `class TemplateResponse(DefaultResponse):` which isn't part of Django.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the code mentioned below -

```
def home(guts): 
  return TemplateResponse(template.render(mt_context1))
```

But, again this introduces another error.

Not sure whether I can post that question here, but as it seems related to this, I'm mentioning it below, anyone pro on this, I could really use some advice :)

Traceback:

```
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/onenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/onenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/onenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/onenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/a/main/wrapper.py" in g
339.                 seed = d[request.method](guts, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/a/main/wrapper.py" in <lambda>
367.     return dispatch_on_method(f, {"GET": lambda guts, *args, **kwargs: f(guts, *args, **kwargs)})

File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/a scratch/a/main/views/base.py" in home
104.     return TemplateResponse(template.render(mt_context1))
```

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'